# mPDF и русские символы

Tags: php, битрикс, pdf

Поставил mPDF. генерирую файл. В нём есть русские символы. В итоге в файле вместо русских символов знаки вопроса.

Создаю mPDF так: `$mpdf = new mPDF('c')`.

Подскажите как сделать что русские символы отображались нормально?

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо в htaccess установить

```
php_value mbstring.func_overload = 0
```

Зная что вы работаете с битриксом — нужно сделать отдельный htaccess для папки или вообще вынести на другой сервер генерацию PDF.

Comment: вынести на отдельный сервер проблема ибо pdf генерируется на лету при создании письма, а мне нужно текст письма.

в каком htaccess это писать?

Comment: Создайте папку и в него положите htaccess и рядом mPDF и скрипт, который будет принимать строку и возвращать ссылку на PDF и функцией CURL обращайтесь к этому скрипту

Comment: а как это сделать на винде? я за htaccess. У меня стоит Веб окружение от самих битриксов.

Comment: Ну у Вас же htaccess в корне лежит?

Comment: Да, вижу. есть. Но вопрос. У меня есть этот файл в корневом каталоге самого сайта (папка www). это то?

Comment: Вам его нужно добавить ещё один в папку.

Comment: В папку какую? не пойму? в папку там где лежит mpdf?

Comment: Повторю ещё раз если Вы принципиально отказываетесь читать то что написано сверху " 
Создайте папку и в него положите htaccess и рядом mPDF и скрипт, который будет принимать строку и возвращать ссылку на PDF и функцией CURL обращайтесь к этому скрипту"

Comment: Сделал так. русский символы всё равно в виду вопросов.

Comment: `$mpdf = new mPDF('utf-8', 'A4', '10', 'Arial', 0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5);
$mpdf->charset_in = 'utf-8';`

Comment: Если я не указываю `('c')` файл не открывается, пишет ошибка при открытии данного документа.